# clear values of all (including nested) form fields within a certain tbody using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure inside of a table, which has rows and also other tables nested within #tbody_name.

```
<tbody id="tbody_name">
    <tr>
        <td>
             <select>
                <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                <option value="3">Something</option>
                <option value="2">Something else</option>
             </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="0" /> Normal<br>
          <input type="radio" value="1" /> Abnormal<br>
        </td>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       <input type="text />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input type="checkbox" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
       </td>
   </tr>          
</tbody>
```

What I am trying to do is write a function that is able to clear the values of all of the form fields within #tbody_name.

I have attempted using .children and .each, but I just cannot seem to boil it all the way down to the form fields within #tbody_name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

JD

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-clear-form/

Comment: You can just wrap the table as a form.. then have a reset button.. or trigger form.reset()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#tbody_name').find('input').each(function(){
    if ((this.type === 'radio') || (this.type === 'checkbox'))
    {
        this.checked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        this.value = '';
    }
});

$('#tbody_name').find('select').each(function() {
    this.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

**EDIT:** I just fixed the code to take care of some rather stupid bugs. It should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can either transverse your table using the find method for finding children, and closest for finding parents, and next for finding the next element:

```
$('#tbody_name').find('option:first-child').attr('selected', 'selected').closest('tr').next().next().find('input:text').val('');
```

Or you can give your form fields ID's and find them by id:

```
$('#defaultOption').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#textInput').val('');
```

Put these inside a function and call it from a button.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways this could be done. Which one you decide to use depends on your coding style. The following solution uses the `prop()` method of jQuery.

```
$('#tbody_name input[type=radio], #tbody_name [type=checkbox]').each(function() {
   $(this).prop('checked', false); 
});

$('#tbody_name input[type=text]').each(function() {
   $(this).prop('value', ''); 
});

$('#tbody_name select').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

Or you could set the properties on the objects expicitly. This method may be a bit more direct and readable:

```
$('#tbody_name input[type=radio], #tbody_name [type=checkbox]').each(function() {
   this.checked = false;
});

$('#tbody_name input[type=text]').each(function() {
   this.value = '';
});

$('#tbody_name select').each(function() {
    this.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```